# What DLL file do I need to add to my solution to use DbSet?

Tags: dll, reference

I am trying to use the generic DbSet class. I have tried adding the following references so far to my solution because [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) states that DbSet lives inside **System.Data.Entity**:

[image: References]

However, as shown below I still cannot add a reference to System.Data.Entity, the only suggestion intellisense has is `EntityClient` which does not contain DbSet:

[image: Intellisense]

Resharper/Intellisense is not giving me any other suggestions of namespaces I could possibly add.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding my solution, and I am using the .Net Framework 4 full version (not the client version).

I have tried using NuGet to search for **EntityFramework** and have found one result which I have added to no avail as is show below:

[image: Entity Framework added]

What DLL file do I need to add to my solution to add a reference to **System.Data.Entity** and use the **DbSet** class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same MSDN reference page that you mention says that you need to reference `EntityFramework.dll` in your project.

Note that namespaces and assemblies are not the same thing. The following statement is a little over-simplified, but you can think of namespaces as residing inside (or becoming available by referencing) an assembly.

So, once you've referenced the assembly, you will still need the `using System.Data.Entity;` directive.